# Dimension of image of one parameter subgroup.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $G$ is a Lie group then $\eta : \mathbb{R}\to G$ is called one parameter subgroup if it is a continuous group homomorphism.

I need to show that the images of one-parameter subgroups in a Lie group $G$ are precisely the connected Lie subgroups of dimension less than or equal to $1$.

I am not getting any idea how to start. Any hints are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The place to start would be to write carefully the definition of a Lie subgroup that you have. Then  compare it with the setting of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, consider the 2-dimensional torus $T^2$, there exists morphisms $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow T^2$ whose image are dense, such an image is not a subgroup since it is not closed.

Comment: As far as I know, they are not group homomorphisms, however.

Comment: really, what make you think that ?

Comment: If they were, the image *would* be a subgroup.

Comment: Never mind, I may see my mistake.

Comment: @TsemoAristide Ok, so how do you know that there exists a homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to T^2$ whose image is dense?

Comment: Frequently, Lie subgroups are not required to be closed, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#Lie_subgroup

Comment: @MoisheKohan that^ was exactly my confusion.

Comment: @Saikat, the dimension $0$ case should not be hard for you. Now for dimension 1, Proposition 5.2, page 34 of Bump's Lie Groups is a very good start. You just need to know via Whitney's Embedding theorem that every Lie group as a manifold, sits inside some $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}=Gl(n, \mathbb{R})$. Now use the matrix exponential.

Comment: Can you conclude from that?

Comment: @TsemoAristide is right about his counterexample. Just precompose the homomorphism $\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{T}^2$ give here (http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~womp/2007/lie2007.pdf) with $exp:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$. We need to require closedness, which is also used in the lemma of Bump's book I cited.

Comment: ^that is clearer to me.